# Redux Form - sync form with Create Operation

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

technologies: using react, Redux, Redux Form (FieldsArray), MongoDB.
I have a list of entities and I want to do the following:

I want to create an entity -> get back from server an entity with _id --> update store with then entity and the _id.

How do I do that?

**actions.js**

```
export function createEntity(entity) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(createEntityStart());
        return axios.post(
            'http://localhost:3000/api/users',
            entity,
        )
        .then(function (response) {
            dispatch(createEntitySuccess(response.entityWithId));
        }).catch(function (response) {
            dispatch(createEntityError(response.data));
        });
    };
}
```

I have done the fields.push({}) - Got a new entity in the component.
Now  I would like to post the new entity which follow a returned entity (with id).
I now need to save the entity with Id somewhere in the store.
How it should be done?
I got in the store:

- form

  - MyFormName

    - values
    - initial
    - registeredFields

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by updating it back to the form values in the right place. Do you want to store the entity ID inside of redux form somewhere for a particular form?

Comment: Thanks for answering - Edited the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to store it in redux-form's state, there are a couple options available. You can look at using redux-form's Action Creators to manipulate its state. Or you can add a plugin into its form reducer (this is a super simplified example):

```
const reducers = {
  form: formReducer.plugin({
    entityForm: (state, action) => { 
      switch(action.type) {
        case CREATE_ENTITY:
          return {
            ...state,
            values: {
              action.payload
            },
            registeredFields: {
              ...state.registeredFields,
            }
          }
        default:
          return state
      }
    }
  })
}
```

You can find more details about redux-form plugins at http://redux-form.com/7.0.3/docs/api/ReducerPlugin.md/

Another option, if you don't want to save it in redux-form's state, is to just create your own state object within redux that stores the entity information.